# Can I search files by capabilities? canAcceptOwnership pendingowner

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

The [Google Drive API docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/ref-search-terms) show some examples of query parameters (q=) on [Files:list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list), but is it exhaustive?  I want something like q="capabilities.canAcceptOwnership=true" but no syntax I try gets anything but a 400 Invalid Value on "q".  What does https://drive.google.com do under the covers when you search there for "pendingowner:me" and nothing else?

You can guess why: I managed to transfer 5000+ files to another user programmatically, but now I need to write the corresponding script to accept them that way, authenticating as the pending owner.  Keep hitting my "Share quota" which I think is related only to the number of emails it sends, where an API call to [Permissions:update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/update) sends no emails, I hope.

Using the "Try this method" [REST thing](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list?apix_params=%7B%22q%22%3A%22capabilities%5BcanAcceptOwnership%5D%3D%27true%27%22%7D) with q of capabilities[canAcceptOwnership]='true' I was hoping to get back a Files:list of only those files whose capabilities[] have canAcceptOwnership=true.

Comment: My workaround is Files:list with q= `"emailaddr" in owners` for the current and losing owner.

Comment: A refinement: `fields=items(...,capabilities/canAcceptOwnership),nextPageToken` and filter it after you get the results.  I can't believe this is what's going on behind pendingowner:me, though.